# Security group through another security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have two AWS Accounts, one database in the main account and one shared VPC betweeen accounts (AWS RAM).

The DocumentDB (database) is configured to use a security group that lives in the main account.

In the secondary account I have access to the VPC but no access to the security groups of the VPC, so I've created a new Security group in this secondary account.

What I want to do is connect to the database of the Main Account from the Secondary Account.

Thannks,

Comment: VPC sharing participants can reference security group IDs of each other. Believe you would simply indicate the security group ID or possibly <account-number>/<security-group-id>. Can you try those?

Comment: You're right, I had to put as inbound rule for one security group the acc-nbr/security-group from the other one. That fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPC sharing participants can reference each other’s security groups via *account-number/security-group-id*